# How to simplify this SCSS border radius Mixin? -- Sass Beginner

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SCSS mixin for which I'm probably writing too much redundant stuff:

```
@mixin radius($topleft, $topright: $topleft, $bottomright: $topleft, $bottomleft: $topleft) {

    -moz-border-radius-topleft:     $topleft;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:    $topright;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: $bottomright;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:  $bottomleft;
    -webkit-border-radius:          $topleft $topright $bottomright $bottomleft;
    border-radius:                  $topleft $topright $bottomright $bottomleft;

}
```

Note the arguments can take a single value to apply for all sides, or all 4 for customization.

Comment: `$bottomleft` variable should be set to `$topright` as default in case you are using shorthand declaration and only passing two variables. Because `border-radius: 0 3px` is equivalent to `border-radius: 0 3px 0 3px`, not `border-radius: 0 3px 0 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could combine the first four lines into:

```
-moz-border-radius: $topleft $topright $bottomright $bottomleft;
```

Apart from that, if you want to retain the option of being able to specify separate values for different edges and keep your code cross-browser compatible, there is nothing you can do to reduce the code anymore.

The syntax of `moz-borer-radius`

```
-moz-border-radius: { { length | percentage }  1 to 4 values | inherit } ;
```

Comment: With the standard mixin DSL there's probably not much else to do, but it could be taken further with some creative [Sass script](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html).

Answer (score 6):

I recomend you to use

```
@import "compass/css3";
@include border-radius(3px);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could explicitly pass values like so:

```
@mixin radius($radius) {

-webkit-border-radius: $radius;
border-radius: $radius;
}
```

Pass arguments like so,

```
.selector {
    @include radius(0 0 5px 5px);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If you use a taskrunner (like grunt) to convert your sass file into css  you could use an autoprefixer to add all the vendor specific prefixes.

https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer

That way you could get rid of the mixin and just write the border radius you'd want.

```
border-radius: 3px 6px 6px 3px
```

And this nice little thingy would convert it for you, and you end up with the same output as your mixin.

Comment: You know full well that is this is not an answer to the question being asked.

Comment: I was quite happy when someone pointed me to this option when I had exactly the same thing. For me it was the perfect answer. So I'd like to pass it on.

Comment: But it's not an answer to this question.  "How do I simplify this mixin" is not answered by "let a 3rd party application fix it for you".